# Retrieve a field of form that is a byte array in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine

I use ASP.NET MVC as my web framework for my game. I have 2 types of requests: string requests that I add it to my form like this:

```
  SendProfileInfoForm.AddField("displayname","dddddd");
```

and I retrieve it on asp like this:

```
 string DisplayName = Request["displayname"];
```

and I have encode png images to byte array that I send it like this:

```
byte[] bytes = SendingAvatar.EncodeToPNG();
Destroy(SendingAvatar);
SendProfileInfoForm.AddBinaryData("avatar", bytes);
```

but I don't know how I can retrieve it in ASP.NET.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `Request.Files`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    // verify file.ContentType
    // do something with file.InputStream
    // etc.
}
```

for just more Complete answer my Code is like below:

```
        var arr = Request.Files.AllKeys;
HttpPostedFileBase x=   Request.Files[arr[0]];
        x.SaveAs("D:\\screenshot.png");
```

Comment: amazing answer. it works. i just edit your answer for more complete answer.